ASP.NET API LinQ constantly get delete all data with condition
I'm having trouble with delete a property so in this code I try to find a property with matching store_id, goods_id, property_id and property_name:
public async Task DeleteGoodsProperty(string storeId, string goodsId, string propertyId ,string propertyName)
{
    var property = await _onlinePosContext.TblGoodsproperties
                .Where(s => s.StoreId == storeId && 
                            s.GoodsId == goodsId && 
                            s.PropertyId== propertyId && 
                            s.PropertyName == propertyName)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (property != null)
    {
        _onlinePosContext.TblGoodsproperties.RemoveRange(property);
        await _onlinePosContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

Expected result: delete property named Chocolate with goods_id is 0030001
Outcome result: delete entire table with the same property_id
Response seem fine
This data will be wiped out after trying to use delete function
I did try to use auto increment for delete specific property but it still delete all.
Both Remove and RemoveRange have the same result

for your code ,you are trying to get only the first one with thoses condistions                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();. Check the "property" value first if it's true
